# C++ std::string.replace doesnt replace, why not?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008, replace

If i use string.replace with ordinary characters its going all well, but as soon as i try to replace a special char like the german "ü" i get no result

```
int main(){
    string s("Gl\\u00fcckstadt");
    string a = "\\u00fc";
    string ue = "ü";
    s = s.replace(s.find(a), a.length(), ue);
    cout << s << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

replace doenst replace the string i need it to replace, any suggestions where i am wrong?

```
int main(){
    string s("Glssckstadt");
    string a = "ss";
    string ue = "ue";
    s = s.replace(s.find(a), a.length(), ue);
    cout << s << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This one will replace the "ss" into "ue" but as soon as i try to replace it with a "ü" it doesnt work...

Comment: strings are not encoding aware, and likely your encoding of nonascii chars is using multiple bytes

Comment: The only thing wrong here is your testing method: http://ideone.com/qm6IhZ. The replace is working fine.

Comment: [Works fine](http://ideone.com/URwrlg) for me.

Comment: If i execute the code i get: Gl³ckstadt as an answer and thats wrong...

Comment: @Andreas, which means your shell is using different encoding to your source code editor

Comment: Print the value of `(int)ue[0]`. If it's 252 then your terminal isn't using the encoding you need (although I'm not sure what mismatch would cause you to see ³, which is 0xB3 in both Unicode and CP1252). If it's some other value then your compiler isn't using the same encoding as your text editor, so you think that your source code contains a "ü" but the compiler disagrees.

Comment: What are the double backslashes doing in your first example? Is that really what you want?

Comment: @Steve Jessop, if i print the value its -4, i use Visual Studio 2008 only

Comment: @Andres: that counts as 252, sorry.

Comment: @JohnB, this case is just to test the replace method, i need it to replace some substrings from my json response